Who's the energy drink guy?
I saw the video for The Lonely Island's "Threw It on the Ground" recently and, approximately 10 seconds in, there's a guy who almost looks like Joel Spolsky. Who's the actor? I'd be very surprised if it's Joel...

The actor you're looking for is Bobby Moynihan and has been frequently seen on SNL since 2008 with appearances in over a hundred episodes.
